# GitHub Action: Ignore tag trigger completely stops the pipeline

Tags: github-actions

Except a tag stated with `v` pushed to the branch, all other action shall start the pipeline

Here is my code

```
on:
  push:
    tags-ignore:
      - "v*"
  pull_request:
    tags-ignore:
      - "v*"
```

Why its stops everything? When I push anything to the branch, nothing is happing with my pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all works as expected, here is an [example](https://github.com/grzegorzkrukowski/stackoverflow_tests/actions/runs/1830576694)

I think you may have a problem of branches versus workflows.

Usually you push all workflows in `master` branches - that's fine.

But for all existing branches it won't work - if workflow doesn't exist on certain branch, it won't be triggered for it.
You have to either rebase branches on top of `master` or cherry pick a commit with your workflow to make it work.